# Variable scope and shadowing in C++ functions and for loops

Tags: c++, selfinitialization

Why does this program print "Hello World"? Undefined behaviour in print function?

```
#include <iostream>

void print(int i) {
    for (int i = i; i<1; i++) {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    std::cout << "i = " << i << "\n";
    print(i);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Tfahsq1Kv

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text*.

Comment: IIRC, in `int i = i` the right hand `i` refers to the left hand `i`, not any prior variable with the same name

Comment: Also, with `int i = i;` you initialize the newly defined variable `i` with itself. And since the value of `i` is *indeterminate* you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Ah, found a source. See **Point of declaration** in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Nitpick: it's not indeterminate (as it would be if it was uninitialized), but rather the variable is accessed before its lifetime starts, which ultimately has the same effect (UB).

Comment: @Shawn That makes sense. But why is not a compile time error?

Comment: Unlike some languages, C++ has no requirement for a compiler to generate a warning, much less an error, when it encounters something it can tell involves undefined behavior.

Comment: *Why is not a compile time error* `int i = i;` was an idiom in olden days to silence a compiler warning about an uninitialized variable. Since such old code is still compiled with modern compilers, they tend to not complain about this particular instance of undefined behavior even thought they easily could. (Consequently, compilers also don't tend to exploit this instance of undefined behavior, either, for optimizations, but do "the right thing".)

Comment: @j6t That's good info on why.

Comment: If you try `-Wall`, the compiler *does* warn. It's just that the setting default is for code from "the bad old days"